# pearson correlation coefficient for model performace

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, prediction, pearson-correlation

Can anyone please tell how to use pearson correlation coefficient for model performanace evaluation? I want to predict pm2.5. the final variables are y_pred and y_actual. I could not find any tutorial.

```
model.fit(x=X_train_scaled, y=y_train_scaled, batch_size=5, epochs=100, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_valid_scaled, y_valid_scaled), shuffle=True)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_scaled)
y_pred_rescaled = Target_scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

what to do after this to get the accuracy using pearson correlation coefficient using python in keras?

Comment: Pearson's correlation coefficient is not used to determine the accuracy of a model. It is used to determine the magnitude of association or correlation. You can use ```scipy.stats.pearsonr(x,y)```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Pearson Correlation Coefficient for checking the performance of the model.

On the other hand, you can use Pearson Correlation Coefficient to check if two variables are strongly correlated, and if so, eliminate one of them, retrain, and check the accuracy of the new model with the eliminated variable. You should expect to get at least the same or even better accuracy/performance, provided that your two variables are strongly correlated.